# Loops and if statements

Tags: java

I would like the program to output how many days it takes to fail the module (to fail the module the mark has to be below 40).
Say you give an input mark of 82 and a number of days of 10.
After 8 times going through loop, the mark will reach 42.
After 9 times it will be 37 (each "day" will decrement the mark by 5).

I can't figure out how can I output how many days will it take for the mark to go below 40.

Here's an example:

```
Mark: 82
Days: 10
```

Output:

```
(0) 82 (1) 77 (2) 72 (3) 67 (4) 62 (5) 57 (6) 52 (7) 47 (8) 42 (9) 37 (10) 32
```

**This work can be up to 8 days late before failing.** (here's the problem)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Late {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int mark;
        int numberOfDays;

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input mark");
        mark = scn.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input number of days");
        numberOfDays = scn.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfDays; i++) {
            System.out.println("(" + i + ")" +  mark);
            mark -=5 ;
            if (mark < 20) {
                System.out.println("Mark cant be lower than 20");
                break;
            }

            }
        if (mark < 40 ) {
            System.out.println("It takes " + numberOfDays + " to fail");

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What is this `(0) 82 (1) 77 (2) 72` syntax? If just a list, then `[82, 77, 72]` is more understandable

Comment: Yes i can deal with the aspect after i finish the algorithm

Comment: `"It takes " + i + " days to fail"`???

Comment: @cricket_007 `i` can continue to increase when `mark` goes below 40, so `i` would not always contain the correct number of days unless you break out of the for loop when `mark` goes below 40.

Comment: i put this in the foor loop    if (mark <= 39 && mark >=34) {
                System.out.println("It takes " + i + " to fail");

Comment: Now it works but the only problem is that i want the output after the mark count its over, now it outputs how many days it takes to fail somwhere in loop, like this:   (9)40
                   It takes 9 to fail
                (10)35
                (11)30

Comment: Add a `break` to stop the output

Comment: I dont want it to stop, i want to output every mark below 40, afterwards to output how many days took for the mark to reach 40

Answer (score 2):

`i` here is the counter for the number of days, and that is what you should print when `mark < 40`

However, do you really need the loop other than check `< 20`?

```
int mark = 82;
int daysToFail = (mark - 40) / 5; // This is 8
if (daysToFail <= numberOfDays) {
    System.out.printf("It takes %d days to fail\n", daysToFail);
} else {
    System.out.println("You passed!");
}
```

If you are required to use the loop, then use `i`, as stated, then add a `break` when you detect `mark < 40`

Comment: I need the loop to stop going lower than 20 , yes

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping?  Why not just:

```
System.out.println("It takes " + (int) Math.ceil((mark-39)/5.0) + " days to fail");
```

, where `mark` is the initial input value?

Comment: In which case, it would print "It takes 13 days to fail".  Is that not the intent?